# Model chegando vazio na controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Basicamente tenho uma `Controller` que envia um `iList` para a `View`, essa `View` poderia editar qualquer registro desse `iList`, porém quando a `Controller` recebe ele já está vazio.

*Fiz assim:*

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{


    var epClientes = db.EstagioProcess
        .Include(etapa => etapa.Cliente)
        .GroupBy(etapa => etapa.ClienteId)
        .Where(grupo => grupo
            .OrderByDescending(etapa => etapa.EpId).Take(1)
            .Select(etapa => etapa.EP)
            .FirstOrDefault() == 2);

    var EP = new List<EstagioProcesso>();
    foreach (var epCliente in epClientes)
    {
        EP.AddRange(epCliente);
    }

    return View(EP);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IList<WMB.MVC.Extranet.Models.EstagioProcesso>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>EP</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>ID Funcionário</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].ClienteId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].EP)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Data)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].IdFuncionario)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Gravar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }}
</table>
```

Veja que coloquei um @Html.BeginForm dentro do for..

e depois fiz na controller para receber

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(EstagioProcesso EP)
    {
//EP Está vazio..não recebe, nda
        EP.EP = Convert.ToByte(Request.Form["Sel_EP"]);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.EstagioProcess.Add(EP);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(EP);
    }
```

**Porque o EP está vindo vazio?** eu deveria receber ele como iList? mas só preciso de um registro..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu parâmetro EP está chegando vazio porque o seu formulário na View não está passando nenhum valor para a sua Action. Através do **@Html.DisplayFor()** você está apenas exibindo seus valores para o usuário, mas você não está gerando nenhum tipo de campo HTML input para que seu formulário envie algo na requisição HTTP.

Os parâmetros de Actions em Controllers MVC funcionam apenas como facilitadores para traduzir os parâmetros enviados pela requisição, seja por Query String em caso de GET ou por POST Data. Quando você coloca um tipo próprio como parâmetro, ele tenta encontrar todos os parâmetros vindos do HTTP com o mesmo nome de cada propriedade do seu tipo para preenchê-lo.

Isso significa que, pela forma como você está preenchendo o seu objeto na primeira Action, provavelmente não será saudável tentar passá-lo inteiro através de uma requisição. Por conta disso, o mais prático é que na primeira Action você apenas pegue os valores que precisam ser exibidos e um campo identificador para que seja possível recuperar qualquer informação importante dele na Action seguinte.

Se o seu objetivo quando o usuário clicar no botão de "Gravar" for descobrir qual dos itens da sua lista que recebeu a ação, então você precisará passar um identificador dele através de um input Hidden:

```
@model IList<WMB.MVC.Extranet.Models.EstagioProcesso>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>EP</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>ID Funcionário</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].ClienteId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].EP)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Data)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].IdFuncionario)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IdEstagioProcesso) @* Aqui viria o campo com o valor que seria selecionado para identificar o seu objeto para consulta posterior *@
                <input type="submit" value="Gravar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }}
</table>
```

E no Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(int idEstagioProcesso)
{
    // você receberá o valor submetido
    // como se trata de um identificador, você consegue recuperá-lo de alguma forma para usá-lo aqui
}
```

Comment: mas essa Action não daria conflito com a que já tenho, afinal ambas recebem um int   Index(int variavel)

Comment: e esse HiddenFor com (m => m) dentro do meu for não encontra nda...seria Model.IdEstagioProcesso ?